# Hamiltonian Monte Carlo with large parameter values fail to converge

Tags: inference, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I'm trying to learn about Hamiltonian Monte Carlo. Therefore I tried to infer the Parameters of a Multivariate Normal given some samples.

My procedure is the following:

- Define $\mu$ and $\Sigma$
- Generate 1000 Samples $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$
- Use HMC to infer $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ from $X$

My implementation works fairly well for a distribution with $\mu = [-1 \; 4 \; 2 \;]^T$ and covariance $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -0.5 & 0.4\\
-0.5 & 4 &-1.5 \\
0.4 & -1.5 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

[image: Trace of Markov chain]

If I change $\mu$ and/or $\Sigma$ to something like $\mu = [-100 \; 400 \; 200 \;]^T$ and $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
200 & -50 & 40\\
-50 & 400 &-150 \\
40 & -150 & 200
\end{bmatrix}$
my implemenation is only capable of infering reasonable values for $\mu$ and the values for $\Sigma$ strongly diverge (see second figure).

[image: Trace of Markov chain]

So far i checked if the gradients are correct and compared them to the numerical gradients and they are both identical. I tried to play with the stepsize $\epsilon$ and the number of steps $L$ of the leapfrog integrator but I wasn't able to alter the results strongly in the latter case.

To generate the plots I used $\epsilon = .005$ and $L = 150$.

Are there any explanations for this behaviour or is something wrong with my implementation?